# .NET Memory leaks and best practice

Tags: .net, vb.net

What is the best way to write functions in Microsoft.NET (VB) to avoid memory leaks.  I have always followed this style:

```
Public Sub TestMemoryLeak()
        Dim testCon As SqlConnection
        Try
            testCon = New SqlConnection
        Catch

        Finally
            If testCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                testCon.Close()
            End If
            testCon = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Here the connection reference is created before the TRY clause and is initialised after the TRY clause.  I believe the connection is always closed and dereferenced even if an exception is thrown.  Is this good practice?  I see a lot of code that creates references and dereferences in the TRY clause, but this would mean that the memory is not correctly handled if an exception is thrown.  Some developers say they don't like to clean up in the finally clause.  I do not fully understand why.

Comment: @SLaks, what do you mean "swallow".  I usually have a global exception handler in Global.asax.  I should have included a THROW statement in the catch clause in the question.  Do you think this is good practice?

Comment: @w0051977 - Yes, you should. Silently failing means you have no idea your code is broken.

Comment: @Oded, would you handle all Exceptions by a global exception handler (which prints to error log and display friendly message) or try to handle some of them in code.

Comment: @w0051977 - It depends... If you can reasonable recover from the exception (i.e. know what to do), handle it. If not, let it bubble up and log it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just use the `Using` statement:

```
Using testConn As New SqlConnection(...)
    ...
End Using
```

This will compile to a `Finally` that will dispose in all circumstances.

Comment: Thanks.  I do use the Using statement, but did not include it in y original question.  Could you explain what you mean by: "This will compile to a Finally that will dispose in all circumstances".  In my example, I test the sonnection state to see if it is open and then close it, if necessary.  Isn't this the same as using the 'Using' statement?

Comment: @w0051977: Yes, but it looks uglier.

Comment: @SLaks, what happens to a connection if an exception is thrown in between Using and End Using.  Is the connection closed? I would test this myself but I don't have access to Visual Studio at the moment.

Comment: @w0051977: Yes, it is.  `Using` compiles to a `Finally` block.